# sybase sql way of converting seconds value to hours minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, date, sybase

In sybase is there any built in functions to convert a seconds value into hours, minutes, and seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is such a function, but if there isn't, the simple formulae are:

```
 HH = floor(seconds / 3600)
 MM = floor(seconds / 60) % 60
 SS = seconds % 60
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want your results formatted as hours:minutes:seconds

```
select convert(varchar(8), dateadd(SECOND, 65, '1970-01-01'), 108)
```

Passing in 65 as our number of seconds results in...

```
00:01:05
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's value limited by 1 day, you can use this:

```
datepart(hour, dateadd(second, value, '1900-01-01'))
datepart(minute, dateadd(second, value, '1900-01-01'))
datepart(second, dateadd(second, value, '1900-01-01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A common 'seconds' dimension is 'seconds since the unix epoch' or 'time_t'. If this is what you are referring to you can do something like

```
select dateadd(SECOND, 123456, '1970-01-01')
```

and you will have a datetime value which can be deconstructed into the various parts via DATEPART

pjjH